# Whenever I brew command anything it keeps saying the same error: "Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/myUserName/Library/Caches/Homebrew"

Tags: python, git, macos, homebrew, macos-mojave

Actually, I am on macOs High Sierra till yesterday but then I discovered that homebrew no longer support this version. So I decided to download and install macOs Mojave overnight and I also thought this will be the solution of my brew doctor warnings but it only made it worse, I can no longer brew command anything on the terminal because it cancels all my brew commands because of this specific error which is Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/myUserName/Library/Caches/Homebrew. I could not complete my any brew commands now. I also tried to search for /Users/myUserName/Library/Caches/Homebrew directory and I think my homebrew folder disappeared or transferred to another directory because it isn't there and I think that this was the problem. But the thing is I don't know what to do. And I am hoping that someone can help me.

BTW just in case you want to know my brew doctor says:

```
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you an update run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.


Warning: Some installed formulae are deprecated or disabled.
You should find replacements for the following formulae:
  ntfs-3g

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3-config
```

and brew config:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.7.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: bca4804a9e48de5319383d3eddadaa7f054c77da
Last commit: 15 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 863b2b39382ed2f77bb2c07aa9f9774661da3792
Core tap last commit: 2 hours ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 4
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/bin/ruby
CPU: quad-core 64-bit broadwell
Clang: 10.0 build 1001
Git: 2.15.0 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 1.8.0_271
macOS: 10.14.6-x86_64
CLT: 10.3.0.0.1.1562985497
Xcode: N/A
```

also when I try brew cleanup:

```
Warning: Skipping bdw-gc: most recent version 8.0.4_1 not installed
Warning: Skipping cask: most recent version 0.8.5 not installed
Warning: Skipping gcc: most recent version 10.2.0_2 not installed
Warning: Skipping gmp: most recent version 6.2.1 not installed
Warning: Skipping guile: most recent version 3.0.5 not installed
Warning: Skipping icu4c: most recent version 67.1 not installed
Warning: Skipping isl: most recent version 0.23 not installed
Warning: Skipping libffi: most recent version 3.3_2 not installed
Warning: Skipping libmpc: most recent version 1.2.1 not installed
Warning: Skipping nettle: most recent version 3.7 not installed
Warning: Skipping node: most recent version 15.6.0 not installed
Warning: Skipping ntfs-3g: most recent version 2017.3.23_3 not installed
Warning: Skipping openssl@1.1: most recent version 1.1.1i not installed
Warning: Skipping p11-kit: most recent version 0.23.22 not installed
Warning: Skipping readline: most recent version 8.1 not installed
Warning: Skipping unbound: most recent version 1.13.0 not installed
Warning: Skipping yarn: most recent version 1.22.10 not installed
Warning: Skipping youtube-dl: most recent version 2021.1.8 not installed
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/myUserName/Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

and lastly what my brew upgrade says which really bothers me:

```
Updating Homebrew...
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/myUserName/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> Upgrading 18 outdated packages:
gmp 6.2.0 -> 6.2.1
nettle 3.6 -> 3.7
bdw-gc 8.0.4 -> 8.0.4_1
icu4c 64.2 -> 67.1
readline 8.0.4 -> 8.1
gcc 10.2.0 -> 10.2.0_2
yarn 1.19.0 -> 1.22.10
ntfs-3g 2017.3.23_1 -> 2017.3.23_3
isl 0.22.1 -> 0.23
youtube-dl 2018.08.28 -> 2021.1.8
openssl@1.1 1.1.1g -> 1.1.1i
cask 0.8.4 -> 0.8.5
node 12.10.0 -> 15.6.0
unbound 1.11.0 -> 1.13.0
guile 3.0.4 -> 3.0.5
p11-kit 0.23.21 -> 0.23.22
libffi 3.3 -> 3.3_2
libmpc 1.2.0 -> 1.2.1
==> Upgrading readline 8.0.4 -> 8.1 
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/myUserName/Library/Caches/Homebrew
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/myUserName/Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

I am hoping someone can really help me here and already have found the solution. FYI also I am new to asking questions here in stackoverflow so I don't know what's the right format or something or what. Kindly correct me or enlighten, Thank You!